# In which thread is the keyPressed() method called?

Tags: java, multithreading, keylistener

Here are two classes:

```
public class Cls implements Runnable, KeyListener
Thread t;
Object obj;
public Cls(Thing obj) {
      this.obj = obj;
...

void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
...
}

void run() {
...

void start() {
if (t != null)
   t = new Thread(this, "we");
t.start();
```

And:

```
public class Main extends JPanel {
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {
         Thing obj = new Thing(stuff);
         Cls cl = new Cls(obj);
         addKeyListener(cls);
         ...
     }
```

(There may be some inccuracies with how to add the `KeyListener` for now, but my point is that it gets added to an instance of `Cls` in the Main class)

Now, if a `KeyEvent` occurs, will the `keyPressed` method run in `main()`'s thread or in `Cls`'? Asking because `Cls`'s thread's `run()` method will run an infinite loop so it will never get around to execute `keyPressed`should it run on `Cls`' thread.

Also, as you can see the `Thing`instance, `obj` is instanciated in Main and passed onto `Cls`' constructor as is. Knowing that `Cls` constantly modifies `obj` and Main uses it (without modifying it in any way), is wrapping the responsible blocks of code with `sychronized`enough to enforce sequential access? Please feel free to give any insight you might want to share.

Comment: The [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Comment: This sounds like a Bad Idea:  `public class Cls implements Runnable, KeyListener`  Every class, every method, every thread in a well designed program should do just _one_ thing.  Your `class Cls` provides both a handler for key presses, and the main method for a thread.  That would be _two_ things, unless you have a different way of looking at it that I don't understand yet.

Comment: Yes, that is part of my asking the question. I mean, I should probably move the `KeyListener` implementation to the `Main` class. The only reason I wrote that way for now is to keep the main class short and focused on the front execution.

Answer (score 4):

AWT event listeners are executed in the event dispatch thread.

Read the [Swing concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Does this mean that the answer is "neither"? Also, I have updated the question with another one, so it'd be appreciated to your opinion on it. (I'm student btw).

Comment: @WIlopu, Yes, it means the answer is "neither".  As soon as your program starts using AWT or Swing, it automatically gets a new thread.  All of your event handlers will be called in that thread and, (this is important!) all of your calls to update GUI objects must be made _from_ that thread.  That is to say, once you have objects on the screen, you should only call GUI framework methods from within an event handler, or by using an `invokeLater` call.  Read the tutorial that JB linked.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Would you mind which kinds of GUI objects do you mean? And how to access the EDT thread? It's my first exposure to multithreading so my knowledge is still shallow.

Comment: All GUI components from the package javax.swing, and their model, must only be used from the EDT. Except for the main method which creates the GUI, and which must used SwingUtilities.invokeLater() as explained in the tutorial, you don't have much to worry about that, because most of the code you'll write that modifies the GUI is code that reacts to events occurring in the GUI, and which thus runs in the EDT already. You have to be careful if you explicitely start background threads.

Comment: @WIlopu, you don't "access" the Event Dispatch Thread; It calls your handlers. For example, after you have called `jpanel.addKeyListener(cls);` then it will start calling `cls.keyPressed(e)` for every keyboard event in your panel.  Besides registering handlers for GUI events, you can also register handlers for timed events by using `javax.swing.Timer`, and you can ask the EDT to promptly call any arbitrary `Runnable` object by using `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r)`.